# How is the possibility of beneficial mutations ensured in the genome?

Tags: evolution, dna, natural-selection, genomes

To ensure natural selection and variability, the genome must have a structure in which the occurrence of beneficial mutations has a high enough probability. But how is this ensured? The space of possible genome configurations (even if we are only talking about "used" regions) is enormous. And the subspace of useful configurations is most likely negligible. That is, the likelihood of a beneficial mutation is extremely small. In this case, how does the genome provide the opportunity for beneficial mutations, which, in turn, provides for infinite evolution?

I want to add that I myself am an ardent supporter of the theory of evolution, so the question is no trick.

Comment: I think you might find this useful reading - it should answer some of your questions http://www.lifesci.susx.ac.uk/home/Adam_Eyre-Walker/Website/Publications_files/EWNRG07.pdf

Comment: OP It is not. @user438383 If you could compose an answer summarising the key points of the paper you cite, I think that would make a useful contribution to SE Biology.